# LINQ to XML querying for sibling elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Sorry if this question is very basic, but I haven't worked with XML very much, and this is my first time working with LINQ to XML...

I have an XML sitemap that is structured like a directory tree:

```
<Site>
    <File GUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx">FileName</file>
    <Folder name="FolderName">
        <Security>
            <Role>Admin</role>
        </Security>
        <File GUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx">FileName</file>
        <Folder name="subFoler">
            <File GUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx">FileName</file>
            <File GUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx">FileName</file>
            <Folder>
                <File GUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx">FileName</file>
            </Folder>
        </Folder>
    </Folder>
</Site>
```

In this way, every file will inherit security from its parent folder (or grandparent folder, etc, depending upon how far up the tree the `<security></security>` is located.

I want to be able to, given a file's GUID, select that file with LINQ, and gather all of the roles associated with the security that file has inherited.

This is what I have so far, but it is a very rough attempt, and is not complete:

```
XDocument sitemap = XDocument.Load(@"\sitemap.xml");
XElement currentFile = new XElement("File", 
        from file in sitemap.Elements("File")
        where file.Element("GUID").Equals(guid)
        select file.Parent.Element("security").Elements("role"));
```

ps. The sitemap file is located within the same directory as the class in which this code is written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to walk up the folder ancestor chain and accumulate the roles you find along the way. You can do that with the aptly-named [Ancestors()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339717.aspx) and [SelectMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) methods:

```
XElement fileFromMap = sitemap.Descendants("File").Where(
    file => file.Attribute("GUID").Value == guid.ToString("D")).Single();

XElement currentFile = new XElement("File",
    fileFromMap.Value,
    fileFromMap.Ancestors("Folder").SelectMany(
        folder => {
            XElement security = folder.Element("Security");
            return (security != null
                ? security.Elements("Role") : new XElement[0]);
        }));
```

**EDIT:** Changed element capitalization to match the updated question.

**EDIT 2:** The code above was mistakenly feeding a `null` item to `SelectMany()` (which is far less indulgent than `XElement.Add()` in this regard), and this [resulted in a `NullPointerException`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6836187/464709). It has been updated to return an empty `XElement` array instead.

Comment: how do I view the security results of this? I've tried `currentFile.Dump()` and `Console.WriteLine(currentFile)`, and I'm just getting the name of the file

Comment: @Jordan, `Console.WriteLine(currentFile.ToString());` should do the trick. You should see `<role>` elements inside the `File` element.

Comment: I'm still only getting `<file>FileName</file>` when I do that? Would it be because I'm using LINQPad? And in case it changes things, I updated my XML example to better clarify how its set up, since, technically there can be 'X' amount of parent folders between a file and its security

Comment: Strange, that should work... Maybe that's a casing problem, are all your elements lower-case like in your question? Is there an XML namespace (`xmlns`) declared somewhere in your markup?

Comment: no...they're actually all first-letter uppercased. And I didn't declare an `xmlns`...just `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at line 1

Comment: @Jordan, XML is case-sensitive: if your elements are capitalized, you need to capitalize their names in the code. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: I actually have done that...I assumed it would be case sensitive.

Comment: @Jordan, so you're using `File`, `Folder`, `Security` and `Role` in your code?

Comment: I was, yes. But I figured the rest out. I was getting a nullreference exception with the `fileFromMap` declaration, so I had changed that code, but that ended up only giving me the filename, so after changing it back to what you initially gave me, it started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I usually do Method syntax but you should be able to convert to query syntax)

```
        XElement currentFile = new XElement("File",
            sitemap.Descendants("file").Where(
               file => file.Attribute("GUID").Value.Equals(guid)).Select(
                   file => file.Parent.Element("security").Elements("role")));
```

Here currentFile should have

```
<File>
  <role>Admin</role>
</File>
```